# Ajax POST never gets sent?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm having an issue with my ajax POST for some reason the POST is never made! can't for the life of me work it out?

yeah so I used the network debug tool in firefox to check the POST request but the POST request never gets made..

The function is definitely getting called too as I have added an alert `alert("start")` to the beginning of the function which does run.

**AJAX**

```
<script>
function updateContentNow(pid2, status2) {
    var mypostrequest = new ajaxRequest();
    mypostrequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (mypostrequest.readyState == 4) {
            if (mypostrequest.status == 200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http") == -1) {
                document.getElementById("livestats").innerHTML = mypostrequest.responseText;
            } else {
                alert("An error has occured making the request");
            }
        }
    }
    var parameters = "cid=clientid&pid=6&statusinfo=approve";
    mypostrequest.open("POST", "http://mydomain.com.au/content-approval/ajax.php", true);
    mypostrequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    mypostrequest.send(parameters);
}
</script>
```

UPDATED WORKING: thanks peps..

```
<script>
function updateContentNow(pid2,status2)
{
var mypostrequest=new XMLHttpRequest()
mypostrequest.onreadystatechange=function(){
 if (mypostrequest.readyState==4){
  if (mypostrequest.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1){
   document.getElementById("livestats").innerHTML=mypostrequest.responseText;
  }
  else{
   alert("An error has occured making the request");
  }
 }
}
var parameters="cid=<?=$clientID?>&pid="+pid2+"&statusinfo="+status2;
mypostrequest.open("POST", "http://mydomain.com.au/content-approval/ajax.php", true);
mypostrequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
mypostrequest.send(parameters);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Looks fine to me... strange.

Comment: exactly what I thought it's been driving me mad! any suggestions? :s

Comment: Perhaps I miss something, but what is `new ajaxRequest` here?

Comment: @rvighne I was wondering the same I just assumed he had a special library to condense all the XML2 and MSXML and whatever testing

Comment: Only thing I'm seeing is maybe a missing `;` after the `new ajaxRequest()`? (i

Comment: @Deryck Maybe. But it would be an uncommonly clever library that exposes it as a class (using `new`). Usually you use a normal function.

Comment: I tried the code. It works fine. I used XMLHttpRequest(). The problem could be with the ajaxRequest.

Comment: Looking again, those parameters `pid2` and `status2` never get referenced either.  Not really significant just being sherlock holmes for a minute

Comment: I guess he might be needing it to send them as parameters. Right now, its hard-coded.

Comment: @Deryck I simplified the code as I was trying to figure out the issue ;P

Comment: @STiTCHiCKED sounds good but what's the deal with ajaxRequest() and is my answer even relevant or do i need to delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using some external Ajax classes, at least ajaxRequest() object doesn't exist in plain JavaScript. Try to substitute this line

```
var mypostrequest = new ajaxRequest();
```

by that:

```
var mypostrequest=new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Then even calling your method with

```
updateContentNow("","");
```

at least makes the POST request as you easily can see with Firebug.

Comment: Okay you are a LEGEND!! don't know where I got that into my head from lol well that did the trick! x